# Can the navigation headbar link to a specific frame in the section, rather than the first one?

Tags: beamer, cross-referencing, navigation

When clicking on a section title in the navigation bar, I arrive quite naturally on the first slide of that section. But when this slide is e.g. a bullet list with pauses between the items, I would rather link directly to the frame where the whole of the bullet list is displayed.

This is because I'll use the nav bar not so much for skipping slides during a talk (I show all of them in sequence), but during questions when I want to show again a specific point.

Is there a way of prescribing this behaviour?

Comment: I've not tested but according to section `8.2.4. The Navigation Symbols` (page 71): "Clicking on the left side of a frame icon will jump to the first slide of the frame, clicking on the right side will jump to the last slide of the frame (this can be useful for skipping overlays)." Therefore, once on the frame you will arrive to the slide with all bullets displayed clicking on the right side of `frame icon`.

Comment: @Ignasi: Thanks for the info, however I'm talking about the navigation bar which displays the outline (ToC) of the talk, not about the "navigation symbols" which are shaded icons (which I actually always disable). Besides, jumping to the last slide of the section can be different from jumping to the last overlay of the first frame in that section.

Comment: Yes I know what you mean. I just wanted to propose some poor man solution. As an example, jumping to the last slide of the section could be done jumping to next section and one slide back.

Comment: @Ignasi: sure, but the aim being to get directly to the point when a question arises, this is not what I'd like to do. In the worth case, I could probably define manually the links in the bar, but there is some chance someone has already coded something similar that could be of use, tweaking '\section' command or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need this for specific sections, you can hack the navigation manually:

In the following example the navigation to the second section jumps the fourth overlay. To adjust this according to you needs, change the `2` in

```
\ifnum#1=2%
```

to the number of the section you want. And the `5` in

```
Navigation5
```

to the page number of the slide the link should point to. In this example, the forth overlay has page no. 5.

---

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames,onlyslideswithnotes,t]{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\usetheme{Frankfurt} 

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\makeatletter
\def\sectionentry#1#2#3#4#5{% section number, section title, page
  \ifnum#5=\c@part%
  \beamer@section@set@min@width
  \box\beamer@sectionbox\hskip1.875ex plus 1fill%
  \beamer@xpos=0\relax%
  \beamer@ypos=1\relax%
  \setbox\beamer@sectionbox=
  \hbox{\def\insertsectionhead{#2}%
    \def\insertsectionheadnumber{#1}%
    \def\insertpartheadnumber{#5}%
    {%
      \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}\usebeamercolor[fg]{section in head/foot}%
      \ifnum\c@section=#1%
        \ifnum#1=2%
            \hyperlink{Navigation5}{{\usebeamertemplate{section in head/foot}}}%
         \else%
                \hyperlink{Navigation#3}{{\usebeamertemplate{section in head/foot}}}%
         \fi%
      \else%
                \ifnum#1=2%
                    \hyperlink{Navigation5}{{\usebeamertemplate{section in head/foot shaded}}}%
                \else%
                    \hyperlink{Navigation#3}{{\usebeamertemplate{section in head/foot shaded}}}%
                \fi%
      \fi}%
  }%
  \ht\beamer@sectionbox=1.875ex%
  \dp\beamer@sectionbox=0.75ex%
  \fi\ignorespaces}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Jump}
\begin{frame}
A 
\end{frame}

\section{section2}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\item 1
\item 2
\item 3
\item 4
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\section{Hide}
\begin{frame}
EF
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering this question! Of course I asked long ago and I'm not even sure what talk I was preparing back then, but I'll test it soon!